# Lubuntu Theme not applied to all programs

Tags: 13.04, lubuntu, themes, gnome-terminal

I am using Lubuntu 13.04, and I have installed `gnome-terminal`. But Its menu buttons are not stylized according to the theme I have chosen (Clearlooks). This issue also appears on some other programs, what can I do to prevent this?

**Addition:** It looks like it is the default theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearlooks is only for gtk2. Check for a theme that provides for both gtk2 and gtk3 themes. For example, the default theme, `lubuntu-default`, has subfolders for both gtk2 and gtk3 in `/usr/share/themes/Lubuntu-default`. Gnome-terminal is a gtk3 app.

You can install other themes from the software center that provide both gtk2 and gtk3 themes: try the `light-themes` or `shimmer-themes` packages, for example.

Answer (score 0):

If your selected theme not  having icon for gnome terminal then it will be blank. So what I am suggesting is set proper icon theme for your lubuntu. Ubuntu tweak tool you needed. That will help you to choose your icons theme.

Terminal Commands to install Ubuntu tweak too
l 
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-tweak-tool`